# Who wins the Side pot if everyone interested in side pot folds

Tags: rules

A. All in $100
B. Raise it to $300
C. Re-Raise it to $600
Then B folds

A turns his cards

C may be protecting A, or doesn't want to show his hand
So C folds his hand
Who does win the side pot?

Comment: Please note that showing the cards in an all-in situation is inevitable. You cannot just muck your hand after committing to an all-in, you have to show your hand and the winner/loser is determined solely based on those cards.

Answer (score 6):

When B folds, the side pot belongs to C, immediately, regardless of what C might later do. If you suspect that C is cheating by protecting A, you are entitled to ask the floorman to expose C's hand and make that judgment.

Answer (score 0):

The main pot is $100 each for $300

There was a side pot between B and C of $200

When C folded A won the main pot

I think C is still entitled to the $200 side pot with B